# Prove whether or not the function is differentiable at (0,0,0)

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose I have a function defined as
$$
f(x,y,z)=\frac{xy+yz+zx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}, (x,y,z) \neq (0,0,0)
$$

and $f(0,0,0) = 0$.

How do I prove whether or not the function is differentiable at $(0,0,0)$?

I've calculated the partial derivatives with respect to $x$,$y$, and $z$ to be $0$ at $(0,0,0)$. The partial derivatives appear to be discontinuous at $(0,0,0)$, so I cannot use the differentiability theorem to say that the function is continuous.

How do I prove or disprove the differentiability of this function at $(0,0,0)$?

Comment: Try using the definition

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the dervative of the function $g$ given by $g(t) = f(t/\sqrt{2},t/\sqrt{2},0)$ at $t = 0$. That is, compute the directional derivative of $f$ along the unit vector $(1,1,0)/\sqrt{2}$.

*If* $f$ is differentiable, then what is derivative equal to in terms of the partial derivatives of $f$? Show that the expression in terms of the partial derivatives of $f$ does not yield the correct result.